# Crystal Reports: Subreport parameter prompts appearing during runtime

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report, subreport

I have a report (that has been used many times in the past) which consists of many subreports. I downloaded it to edit a word within a text box in one of the subreports, and made NO other changes. After I uploaded the new version onto the server, I went to reschedule it. Here’s where the problem comes in, the scheduler suddenly displays a bunch of subreport parameter prompts after the main report parameter fields. These subreport parameters have never shown up previously. Before, the scheduler would only prompt the user to fill in the main report parameters.

It should be noted that the report will still run without error if I only fill in the main report parameters and ignore the subreport ones. Also, when I run this report locally, I’m only prompted for the main report parameters (the subreport parameters do not appear). Lastly, I maintained the unedited version of the report, rolled it back onto the server, and still got the same issue. I checked all the subreport links and they are linked to the main report. Can someone please assist?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mr. DK, it may help to include the type of scheduler you are using as it sounds like that is probably the case here.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, it's Business Objects XI Release 1 (I hope that helps).

Comment: if you run this directly in CR does it work correctly?

Comment: Yes, it works correctly when I run this directly in CR.

Comment: I'm at a loss with this one, the only thing that I can think of is different CR versions, and the SDK used by the software is causing issues.  If this is software from a vendor I would send them an e-mail asking what version of CR the software supports.

Comment: Be sure to UNcheck the option "Save Data with Report" (menu File).

Also check the subreport parameter links (right mouse button over the subreport -> Change subreport links...)

I have had that problem before and it was gone after I checked these out.

Suggestion: Never delete an old version of a report; because there can be stupid (because we can't seem to understand them) errors that come out of nothing, you should always keep a working version in backup before changing them. No matter what's the change.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue: Our BusinessObjects server randomly decided to prompt me to enter a paramenter that is being correctly passed from my Main report to one of its Subreport, despite Crystal Reports 2008 (SP5) not prompting me when I run it directly from Crystal Reports.

Try this to resolve it:
Right click the subreport in question, choose Change Subreport Links, and uncheck the box "Select data in subreport based on field".  The subreport still has a reference to this parameter because initially when passing the parameter you checked that box just like you should do.
Hope this helps.

Comment: In my situation, passing the param into the subreport link was deleted while upgrading the crystal version so we were getting invalid param count in C#. Re-adding the main report selecting within the subreport based on the parameter fixed the issue.